# How can I insert an operation sign betwen 2 float numbers and calculate the result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
numbers =[2.4, 3.5, 0.5]
operations = ['+', '-']
```

Note that the values in operations will be changed so I cant just type:

```
solution = numbers[0] + numbers[1]
```

I need to insert the value of `operations[0]` between those numbers.

I've tried:

```
solution = numbers[0] + operations[0] + numbers[1]
```

But I can't merge floats and strings values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every operator in Python is [available through the `operator`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html) module. This allows you to dynamically use the operators as you see fit.

Instead of referencing a string version of the operator, you include the function itself in your list and then call it:

```
import operator

numbers = [2.4, 3.5, 0.5]
operations = [operator.add, operator.sub]

print(operations[0](numbers[0], numbers[1]))
#      ^-- identical to operators.add(numbers[0], numbers[1])
```

Comment: You can use a dictionary to hold the operations: `d = {'+': operator.add, 
     '-': operator.sub, 
     '*': operator.mul, 
     '/': operator.truediv}`

Comment: Yup - if OP needs to resolve them from their string counterparts, that's the way to do it. The original question wanted to reference them from a list by index, so I kept it that way.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for something similar in math library

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lambda` expressions to represent the operators:

```py
numbers =[2.4, 3.5, 0.5]
operations = [lambda x,y: x + y, lambda x,y: x - y]

solution = operations[0](numbers[0], numbers[1])
```

Note that this will **not** calculate the values pre-hand, only when you actually call the functions.